# Redirect into New Page after Background Fades Android

Tags: android, background, fading

I wanted my app to had a fading picture first before going into another page using threads. Below is the code i used and it worked well for me. However, it stops in the white page at the end of the thread. What will i do so that it will go to the next activity without clicking on anything? Or after the page turns white, what code should i use so that it will go now to the next activity?

```
package com.kfc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Intro extends Activity {
    LinearLayout screen;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int i;
    Intent intent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.introxml);

        screen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myintro);

        (new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                for(i=0; i<255; i++){
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, i, i, i));
                        }
                    });
                    // next will pause the thread for some time
                    try{ sleep(10); }
                    catch(Exception e){ break; }
                }
                for(i=255; i>0; i--){
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, i, i, i));
                        }
                    });
                    // next will pause the thread for some time
                    try{ sleep(10); }
                    catch(Exception e){ break; }
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(Intro.this,NewKFCActivity.class));
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: When any answer match your criteria..Accept it so other user can get to know..and it helps other to find the solution those worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the for loop exits. Add the code to start a new activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intro.this,NewACtivity.class));
```

You need to put it outside the for loop. If you put it after start method, it will execute before the thread is completed. You may also need to scope the 'this variable' using Intro.this. Also remember to add the new activity in the manifest file as

```
<activity android:name=".NewActivity"/>
```

Just use this

```
screen = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
(new Thread(){
    @Override
public void run(){
    for(i=0; i<255; i++){
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, i, i, i));
            }
        });
        // next will pause the thread for some time
        try{ sleep(100); }
           catch(Exception e){ break; }
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(TabTester.this,NewKFCActivity.class));
    }
}).start();
```

this pointer should point to the Intro activity object. But inside the thread, this will refer to the the current thread object(am not sure to what it point exactly) so you need to scope it using 'Intro.this' which mean 'use this that points to the Intro activity'

You background picture will be overwritten when you use setBackgroundColor to the same view. A way to do this will be to use to layouts, the outer layout will have the background picture and the inner layout will be the one that has setBackgroundColor applied to. 
Eg:

You also need to alter the code

```
screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, i, i, i));
```

to

```
screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(120, i, i, i));
```

The alpha value is set to 255 which means opaque and will not show the background image.

Comment: does that mean before }).start();? it did not work.. it gives an error "The constructor Intent(new Thread(){}, Class<NewKFCActivity>) is undefined"

Comment: thanks! it worked! :) i had another question.. hopefully you can help me.. how can i then start from having a background picture into this? i run my program and it start from black to white.. i wanted from a picture to white.. thanks

Comment: i tried the code and changed TabTester into Intro.this, but it force-closes.. maybe because of FrameLayout?

Comment: Tabtester is just a test file I created. Replace it with Intro.this. Whats the error log saying?

Comment: i figured out that the xml file is linearlayout so i changed it to framelayout.. the program ran, however the program started from black background, not from a picture (the background of the XML file)

Comment: The framelayout came from a test program I made. Just keep your xml file and replace the framelayout in my code with linearlayout.

Comment: i already did that but still it starts from black to white.. my xml has the background picture

Comment: by the way, you can check out the updated code i pasted above

Comment: it still did do any good :( are you sure with this? i really tried but does not do any good..

Comment: Make it another question. will get others attention